# use tf–idf in keras Tokenizer

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, nlp

I have a dataframe where the column Title of the first row contains this text:

```
Use of hydrocolloids as cryoprotectant for frozen foods
```

Using this code:

```
vocabulary_size = 1000
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=vocabulary_size)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df['Title'])
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df['Title'])
print(sequences[0])
```

I am getting this sequence:

```
[57, 1, 21, 7]
```

Using this:

```
index_word = {v: k for k, v in tokenizer.word_index.items()}
print(index_word[57])
print(index_word[1])
print(index_word[21])
print(index_word[7])
```

I obtain:

```
use
of
as
for
```

It makes sense, as these are the more frequent words. Is it also possible to use the Tokenizer to base the tokenisation on [tf–idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)?

Increasing the vocabulary_size also tokenises less frequent words like:

```
hydrocolloids
```

I intend to use glove downstream for a classification task. Does it make sense to keep frequent and thus potentially less discrimitative words like:

```
use
```

in? Maybe yes, as glove also looks at context, which is in contrast to bag of word approaches I used in the past. Here tf–idf makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

Until now (because Keras always updating its functions), there is nothing can produce what you want ..

But it has a function that represent the sequences using Tf-Idf scheme instead of freq.:

```
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(df['Title'], mode='tfidf')
```

instead of:

```
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df['Title'])
```

Also, as a suggestion, you can use sklearn TfidfVectorizer to filter the text from the low frequent words, then pass it to your Keras model ..

Comment: But does this filter to the top words by tf-idf score or simply encode the matrix using tf-idf?

Answer (score 2):

The num_words argument to Tokenizer() can help you achieve this.

Here is the description from the documentation: "the maximum number of words to keep, based on word frequency. Only the most common num_words-1 words will be kept."

The smaller the num_words you provide, the more rare words it will exclude. If you don't specify that argument, all words will be included, even the rarest ones.

When you are *building* your tokenizer, what you are really looking for is to account for the *document frequency*, which is the number of documents the word appears in. *tf-idf* is not applicable yet, because the *term frequency* refers to how many times a word appears **in a particular document.**